# how to rejoin words that are split accross lines with a hyphen in a text file

Tags: regex, linux, text

OCR texts often have words that flow from one line to another with a hyphen at the end of the first line. (ie: the word has '-\n' inserted in it).

I would like rejoin all such split words in a text file (in a linux environment).

I believe this should be possible with sed or awk, but the syntax for these is dark magic to me! I knew a text editor in windows that did regex search/replace with newlines in the search expression, but am unaware of such in linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat file | perl -p -e 's/-\n//'
```

If the file has windows line endings, you'll need to catch the `cr-lf` with something like:

```
cat file | perl -p -e 's/-\s\n//'
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to back up `ocr_file` before running as this command will modify the contents of `ocr_file`:

```
perl -i~ -e 'BEGIN{$/=undef} ($f=<>) =~ s#-\s*\n\s*(\S+)#$1\n#mg; print $f' ocr_file
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is relevant, because I want the words joined together... not just a removal of the dash character.

```
cat file| perl -CS -pe's/-\n//'|fmt -w52
```

is the short answer, but uses `fmt` to reform paragraphs after the paragraphs were mangled by perl.

without fmt, you can do

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use open qw(:std :utf8);
undef $/; $_=<>; 
s/-\n(\w+\W+)\s*/$1\n/sg;
print;
```

also, if you're doing OCR, you can use this perl one-liner to convert unicode utf-8 dashes to ascii dash characters.  note the -CS option to tell perl about utf-8.

```
# 0x2009 - 0x2015 em-dashes to ascii dash 
    perl -CS -pe 'tr/\x{2009}\x{2010}\x{2011}\x{2012\x{2013}\x{2014}\x{2015}/-/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey this is my first answer post, here goes:

'**-\n**' I suspect are the line-feed characters. You can use sed to remove these. You could try the following as a test:

1) create a test file:

**echo "hello this is a test -\n" > testfile**

2) check the file has the expected contents:

**cat testfile**

3) test the sed command, this sends the edited text stream to standard out (ie your active console window) without overwriting anything:

**sed 's/-\\n//g' testfile**

(you should just see 'hello this is a test file' printed to the console without the '**-\n**')

If I build up the command:

a) First off you have the sed command itself:

**sed**

b) Secondly the expression and sed specific controls need to be in quotations:

**sed 'sedcontrols+regex'** (the text in quotations isn't what you'll actually enter, we'll fill this in as we go along)

c) Specify the file you are reading from:

**sed 'sedcontrols+regex' testfile**

d) To delete the string in question, sed needs to be told to substitute the unwanted characters with nothing (null,zero), so you use '**s**' to substitute, forward-slash, then the unwanted string (more on that in a sec), then forward-slash again, then nothing (what it's being substituted with), then forward-slash, and then the scale (as in do you want to apply the edit to a single line or more). In this case I will select '**g**' which represents global, as in the whole text file. So now we have:

**sed 's/regex//g' testfile**

e) We need to add in the unwanted string but it gets confusing because if there is a slash in your string, it needs to be escaped out using a back-slash. So, the unwanted string 
**-\n** ends up looking like **-\\n**

We can output the edited text stream to stdout as follows:

**sed 's/-\\n//g' testfile**

To save the results without overwriting anything (assuming testfile2 doesn't exist) we can redirect the output to a file:

**sed 's/-\\n//g' testfile >testfile2**

Comment: a bit verbose... better perhaps to work out how to do it and post just that, perhaps with an explanation of each bit if you like. Thanks for the answer anyway (:

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -z 's/-\n//' file_with_hyphens
```

Comment: as written, will only replace the first instance. `sed -z 's/-\n//g'` is more effective